# How to detect image file extension in a string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how can I detect an image in a string with JavaScript. For example, I have an input type text that has the following value, "Hey check this out https://exmaple.com/image.jpg" I want to wrap 'https://exmaple.com/image.jpg' in an  tag so it can show the image right away in my site. Thank you, I tried using the split function in JavaScript but I don't know how to detect the image extension in the string.

Comment: No that's how you get the extension what i need is to detect it in string and wrap it in a image tag

Comment: OK, I understand now. Retracted close vote that would close as a duplicate!

Answer (score 7):

Use `lastIndexOf()`

```
var str = "https://example.com/image.jpg";
var dotIndex = str.lastIndexOf('.');
var ext = str.substring(dotIndex);
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TC98F/)

Comment: simple but make sanse, thx

Answer (score 3):

You'd probably want to use a regular expression like the following in order to find any image type, and make sure you're not returning other junk that you don't want. E.g.

```
'https://exmaple.com/image.jpg'.match(/[^/]+(jpg|png|gif)$/)
-> ["image.jpg", "jpg"]
```

Comment: That would work for the string he provided, but not for `Hey check this out https://exmaple.com/image.jpg it is great`.

Comment: It would work if the user continued to split on whitespace though.

Answer (score 2):

```
var str = "https://example.com/image.jpg";
var extArray = str.split(".");
var ext = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
```

Try this.

```
function searchText(text)
{
  var arr = text.match("/(http|ftp|https)://[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;/~+#-])?/");
  for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
  {
    //Make tags where 'arr[i]' is your url. 
  }
}
```

Comment: I will add searching in text in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: (Please use logic based on your needs)
you have to split string somehow based on your condition and check if the string has . or something

```
var a = "Hey check this out https://exmaple.com/image.jpg";
var text = a.split(' ');
```

if text array has your condition then assign to variable filename

```
if(jQuery.inArray(".", text)!==-1) { //i dont prefer only .
filename = text[jQuery.inArray(".", text)];
}
```

separate the extension

```
function getExt(filename)
{
    var ext = filename.split('.').pop();
    if(ext == filename) return "";
    return ext;
}
```